# How to disable web page audio on mobile divices during screen locking or minimizing browser?

Tags: javascript, audio, mobile, html5-audio, web-audio-api

If there is sound playing on your web page, you can lock the screen or minimize the browser, but the sound still plays. How can I turn off the sound in current cases?

Answer (score 0):

try `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);`, actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active) is your question

Comment: Ok, looks like it's working if audio is standalone, but if playing video player in parallel with audio, video is muted, but audio still playing